# How to define global dummy document object for angular 2+ universal?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-universal

I'm using angular v6 and trying to build app with angular universal. 
And there is a known issue with access to such objects as `document`, `window` and so on.

For my own code, sure thing, i can inject `PLATFORM_ID` and use `isPlatformBrowser`.

For example:

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.PLATFORM_ID)) {
  const el = document.getElementById('id');
}
```

The problem is when some third-party library (in my case) uses `document.getElementsByTagName('script')`.

Is there a way to define global dummy `document` object with declared `getElementsByTagName`, `getEelementById` and other methods which actually will do nothing but won't throw an error when app tries to access `document` object as global one in `platform-server`?

Or maybe there is another elegant way to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You can set a global by setting it on `global`, ie `global.document` and from there just write empty functions: `global.document = { getElementsByClassName:()=>{} }` Though you might want to actually return the values returned by the native functions, ie `null` for `getElementById()`, empty array for getElementsBy* functions etc.

Comment: hmm tried that way, but still get an error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

Comment: Are you defining it before whatever code calls for document? ie setting it up before any and all `require()` calls?

Comment: yeah, moved it in my `app.module.ts` on the very top before importing `NgModule`

Comment: found what exactly causes the error, probably the best way for now is just to make those imports conditional on the platform, but still interesting with mocking global objects. anyway thanks @PatrickEvans !